# Azure ManagementClient.Subscriptions.Get() hangs forever. Need workaround

Tags: azure, freeze

My every attempt to call ManagementClient.Subscriptions.Get() hangs forever.
If I change it to ManagementClient.Subscriptions.GetAsync(), and run it on its own thread, the task stays in WaitingForActivation state forever.

Any suggestions?

Sample Code: (it's the last line that hangs.)

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Models;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

class Program1
{
    static void Main1(string[] args)
    {
        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(...);
        AuthenticationResult authResult = context.AcquireToken(...);
        TokenCloudCredentials token = new TokenCloudCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
        ManagementClient client = new ManagementClient(token);
        SubscriptionGetResponse subresp = client.Subscriptions.Get();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, error recovery is lacking in `Subscriptions.Get` and friends. My problem was that the URL in `context.AcquireToken` was wrong. I had "https://management.core.windows.net", but needed "https://management.core.windows.net/" (i.e., the trailing slash made all of the difference.)